# Swift using a variable in another function

Tags: swift, function, variables

How can I call testArray from `locationManager()` in `callTestArray()` ?
I tried outputting it but that doesn’t seem to work. I also tried to declare at the top of my class but then it’s always `nil`.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
    let geoRef = GeoFire(firebaseRef: rootRef.child(“X”))
    let query = geoRef.query(at: userLocation, withRadius: 1000)

    query.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in
        self.testArray.insert(key, at: self.testArray.count)
    })
}

func callTestArray() {
    var testOuput = testArray[0]
}
```

Comment: by the way, you can just use `self.testArray.append(key)` instead of `insert`. Everything should work correctly if you call `callTestArray` after the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: String, didUpdateLocations locations: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
   let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
   let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
   let geoRef = GeoFire(firebaseRef: rootRef.child(“X”))
   let query = geoRef.query(at: userLocation, withRadius: 1000)
   query.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in
       self.testArray.append(key)
       completion()
   })
}
```

Usage:

```
locationManager(XXXXXX, didUpdateLocations: YYYYYY) {
    callTestArray()
}
```